# allow the page only goes specifies page number

Tags: php, mysql

i want to load page through pagination in specific page no. if the count of the total row is 0 then page no should be one if the count is 10 then page no should be 11
my code is

```
$newinc=$db->get_row("SELECT count(*) as count2 FROM store where survey_name='$_SESSION[ssn_sname]' and dateone='$_SESSION[vdate]' and branch='$_SESSION[branch]' ");
$count11=$newinc->count2;
$page1=$count11+1;  
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=srv_form.php?page=$page1'>";
```

this is why i m trying to do that while doing survey if the network down then the page start from page no one so, how can i do like that..

Comment: So if code is not working or any other problem ?

Comment: Personally I will prefer php header function instead of meta refresh.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj no i am trying to get if the row count is 10 then page number should be 11 in my pagination. ORDER BY c.p_order
  LIMIT $start, $limit"; this is the code but i have no idea hot to get particular page

Comment: MySQL LIMIT statement help you to extract page specific records for that page. When you are talking about to goto page like  srv_form.php?page=3, Then it is alternative and maybe better to use php header location like header('location: srv_form.php?page=3') instead of html meta refresh.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj i put there header function but it wont work

Comment: Remember before using header function, there must not be any echo print or any html rendering.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj thank you for your great support. in srv_form have question and answer. and process page have storing code into the database and it redirect to the srv_rdr page and in srv rdr page, it count total no stored and increase the value and again redirect it to the srv_form is this technique is ok or should i need to change it? actually problem is sometime networking error come while doing survey and its start from the beginning so i want to short out this problem. is it ok or should i need to change? please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect solution must be like that for replacing meta refresh with php header function.

```
$newinc=$db->get_row("SELECT count(*) as count2 FROM store where survey_name='".$_SESSION['ssn_sname']."' and dateone='".$_SESSION['vdate']."' and branch='".$_SESSION['branch']."' ");
$count11=$newinc->count2;
$page1=$count11+1;  
header("location: srv_form.php?page=$page1");
```

If you have page is not redirected there must be problem with something print or render. You can verify with apache logs which will give you the warnings about this.

Comment: error came saying "The webpage at http://localhost/survey/srv_form.php?page=15 has resulted in too many redirects."

Comment: Now you must control the redirection code to allow rediirct only in special cases. Normally in pagination redirection done by html anchor not by php. If you need this you must check if value of page query string in current uri and $page1 variable must not be the same.

Comment: thank you for your great support. in srv_form have question and answer. and process page have storing code into the database and it redirect to the srv_rdr page and in srv rdr page, it count total no stored and increase the value and again redirect it to the srv_form is this technique is ok or should i need to change it? actually problem is sometime networking error come while doing survey and its start from the beginning so i want to short out this problem. is it ok or should i need to change? please guide me.